# IDA Convert to Unicode

Tags: ida, encodings

In IDA 5.0 Freeware how do you convert a block of data into a unicode string, the only thing I can find is to convert it into an ascii string.

```
db 'a'
db 0
db 'b'
db 0
db 'c'
db 0
db 'd'
db 0
db 0
db 0
```

into

```
unicode <abcd>, 0
```

Comment: if you get a long sequence of this type means executable need unpacking..

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to bring up the "string style" dialog, from which you can create a string of various types (including Unicode).  Through this dialog, you can optionally set the default string type that is created when you press <kbd>a</kbd> (i.e., you can make it such that Unicode is the default if you want).

Alternatively use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>U</kbd> as pointed out by [joxeankoret](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/users/111/joxeankoret) in the comment.

Comment: I really like shortcuts: Alt-A+U (it's the same).

Answer (score 5):

Select the first byte, Edit -> Strings -> Unicode.